# understanding CSS declarations inside flexboxgrid

Tags: css

I was just going through the code of this framework [HERE](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/blob/master/src/css/flexboxgrid.css#L2)

I see stuff like

```
:root {
  --gutter-width: 1rem;
  --outer-margin: 2rem;
  --gutter-compensation: calc((var(--gutter-width) * 0.5) * -1);
  --half-gutter-width: calc((var(--gutter-width) * 0.5));
  --xs-min: 30;
  --sm-min: 48;
  --md-min: 64;
  --lg-min: 75;
  --screen-xs-min: var(--xs-min)em;
  --screen-sm-min: var(--sm-min)em;
  --screen-md-min: var(--md-min)em;
  --screen-lg-min: var(--lg-min)em;
  --container-sm: calc(var(--sm-min) + var(--gutter-width));
  --container-md: calc(var(--md-min) + var(--gutter-width));
  --container-lg: calc(var(--lg-min) + var(--gutter-width));
}

@custom-media --sm-viewport only screen and (min-width: 48em);
@custom-media --md-viewport only screen and (min-width: 64em);
@custom-media --lg-viewport only screen and (min-width: 75em);
```

What on earth is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's CSS Variables. Welcome to the future.

See more information:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Thank you, added that to the answer.